# How to know whether user rated app on appstore

Tags: ios, itunes

I open following link : `itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=#appid#&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software` for rating the app on app store.

Can I come to know whether user actually rated the app in App Store or not, or just opened the link.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot know whether the user has rated the app. But when you send the user to the appStore we assume in good faith that the user would have rated the app. You will unfortunately not know this since apple won't give you the feedback on it. The best you can do is give them the "rate my app link" and attribute them with the points if they click on it.

Another option is through your own apple Id(checking manually on the website).

Answer (score 2):

You have no way to verify that an user has rated your app. To rate an app, user use his iTunes account, which you have no information about from an app.